# Using parsel in Scrapy project

Tags: python, html, scrapy, screen-scraping, parsel

I'm trying to use the parsel library to scrape elements from a html file in a Scrapy project. This is my spider codes, named `123Spider` :

```
import scrapy 

import requests

class 123Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "123Spider"
    start_url = [
    'file://URI'
]

    def parse(self, response):

        for commentSelector in response.css("div._li"):
            yield {
                'comment': commentSelector.css('#js_ajn > p').extract(),
        }
```

when I run `scrapy crawl 123Spider -o output.json` from command line, it exports an empty JSON file. Terminal shows this process:

```
2018-01-03 14:44:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-01-03 14:44:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx.html> (referer: None)
2018-01-03 14:44:20 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx.html>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is Error 404 & 400 returned crawling the .html file? It worked fine both when I run a pure parsel .py file, as well as within scrapy shell. (the html file is >10MB)
2. How to correctly nestle parsel elements within my 123Spider class?

Searched existing questions but none match my scenario.

**Update:**
The aim is to parse a .html file that already exists in my spider project structure. However when crawling `file://URI`, terminal shows no pages crawled. There's no typo in my URI, tested with scrapy shell.

```
2018-01-04 14:40:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-01-04 14:40:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-04 14:40:14 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-01-04 14:40:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-01-04 14:40:14 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 21, 40, 14, 392659),
'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'memusage/max': 55623680,
'memusage/startup': 55619584,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 21, 40, 14, 374933)}
2018-01-04 14:40:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: You shouldn't literally have `file://URI` there... here's a link explaining what a file URI is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme You should use one matching your local file

Comment: yeah...I put the correct file structure in my codes, and when tested with scrapy shell, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy already uses parsel selectors by default, so there is no need for you to even import it - `response.xpath()` and `response.css()` use the methods of the underlying parsel selector.
Knowing that, you can just remove the 4 lines importing `Selector` and creating an instance of it.

The real problem seems to be the 404, which simply means the document you were trying to access wasn't found.
My first guess would be that you have a typo in your `start_urls`. If that's not the case, you'll need to share the actual url you're trying to scrape.

The 400 error is just scrapy trying and failing to access the robots.txt file.
You could disable the `RobotsTxtMiddleware` to stop this from happening, but there is no real benefit, it will cause you no problems and can be ignored.

Comment: I wanted to use parsel specifically because I already have that .html file in my spider project, so it will bypass that 404 or other url crawling error. I'm not sure how to point to it, though.

Comment: Scrapy will have no problem parsing a local file, just give it a file:// URI

Comment: Thank you, your answer addressed the initial concern of using parsel in Scrapy. Was wondering if you can take a look at my most recent update to the question, though, as when I try `file://URI` , it is still not working. I suspect it's my spider code...

Comment: Update your question with the current code, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you worked fine when running a standalone script file or working well within scrapy shell,one possible cause is blocked by spider middleware,
when running by `scrapy crawl`command,the [default middleware list](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE) would be involved the running process.

You can ref details at [Scrapy 404 error: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030717/scrapy-404-error-http-status-code-is-not-handled-or-not-allowed/48031332#48031332)

If this issue is not this case,you'll may share your real url that you are scraping for further investigation

Thanks.

Comment: Was hoping not to have to change the middleware configuration (at my level of understanding I think it'll cause me problems that I can't solve in future projects). Since I already have the full .html file, maybe I don't have to use `scrapy crawl` at all? Updated the question to reflect what I'm trying to do.