# 404 response in scrapy shell, different results in browser

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping the site oddsportal, just a simple query for the title text returns ['OddsPortal: Page not found'] however in the browser console this ['OddsPortal: Page not found'] does not appear. I have noticed when the shell loads the response is:

```
[s]   response   <404 https://www.oddsportal.com/darts/europe/european-championship/results/>
```

In my terminal

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.oddsportal.com/darts/europe/european-championship/results/' --set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False"

response.css('title::text').extract()
['OddsPortal: Page not found']
```

I would be expecting from the above selector:

European Championship Results & Historical Odds, Darts Europe Archive

Comment: I was able to scap the URL after changing the USER_AGENT as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862053/406423

Comment: @MadMike that worked!

Comment: I'm happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also get this error when running my own request. As shown [here](https://www.oddsportal.com/robots.txt) this site does not allow scraping. My guess is they have some guards in place to prevent you from trying. I am having success using a non headless version with selenium. I would recommend doing your scraping that way. It also looks like most of the site is dynamic javascript, so thats another +1 for selenium. I am using Beautiful soup to parse in this example, and I highly recommend it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/darts/europe/european-championship/results/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.text)

#output
#European Championship Results & Historical Odds, Darts Europe Archive
```

Comment: I used the flag ```--set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False"``` however it still returns the same

Comment: I added a working example here with selenium for you. If you haven't used selenium before read the simple usage in the docs.

Comment: Thanks but I think it's too slow for this use case